# The "at" thing isn't working...

Tags: support, comment-replies

Today when I start a comment with "@someone" the @someone part doesn't appear in my comment. What gives? (Logged off and came back, no change...)

Comment: If the target is already notified by default then the software removes the redundant explicit notification.

Comment: See also [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6281/weird-reoccuring-bug-someone) and [several related posts](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/6281).

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks - curious I never noticed.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich what Bill Dubuque said is mainly true but not literally. (As this comment proves.)

Comment: You can find further details in the MSO thread [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)